# jcenter Returns Error 403 Forbidden, what should we use instead?

Tags: maven, gradle, jcenter

Seems **jcenter** service does not work at all and returns **403 Forbidden**
and also deprecated in IntelliJ products (Like Android Studio)

What should be used instead?

https://jcenter.bintray.com/

Comment: Central repository ... https://central.sonatype.org/ https://repo1.maven.org/ https://search.maven.org ...

Answer (score 11):

After many investigating I found some suitable repositories, you can use

`mavenCentral()`

instead of

`jcenter()`

And also you need to check your connection and **Proxy** if you use

Comment: [MvnRepository](https://mvnrepository.com/) does not, despite its name, host a Maven repository. Rather, it serves as an information hub aggregated from multiple other repositories. If you use Gradle, for most dependencies, you can just use `mavenCentral()` instead of `jcenter()`.

Comment: for many libraries there is no host for them in maven central, if you create even a new project without cache, it won't be build

Comment: My point is that you can't use `MvnRepository` as a Maven repository in your Gradle project. You can only look up information in a browser. What you can normally do is to add `mavenCentral`, and for those (in my experience very few) dependencies that are in other repositories, you add those where needed. And if you are in doubt about what repository a given library has been uploaded to, MvnRepository can usually help you.

Comment: yes, you are right, I updated the answer, and will update it when new repository deployed

Comment: You still only need `mavenCentral()`. The other URL you have is the old one for Maven Central.

Answer (score 3):

Today 16-09-2021 our flutter pipeline stopped working for no apparent reason.

I had to update some gradle versions, and then I ran into this issue:
`Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug` and `Read timed out`

**Error log:**

```
    [        ] "Install Android SDK Platform 30 (revision: 3)" complete.
    [        ] "Install Android SDK Platform 30 (revision: 3)" finished.
    [+1706 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    [        ] * What went wrong:
    [        ] Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'.
    [        ] > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
    [        ]    > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-05e680e202af9a92461070cb2d9982acad46c83c.
    [        ]      Required by:
......
    [        ]       > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-05e680e202af9a92461070cb2d9982acad46c83c.
    [        ]          > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-05e680e202af9a92461070cb2d9982acad46c83c/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-05e680e202af9a92461070cb2d9982acad46c83c.pom'.
    [        ]             > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-05e680e202af9a92461070cb2d9982acad46c83c/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-05e680e202af9a92461070cb2d9982acad46c83c.pom'.
    [        ]                > Read timed out
    [        ] * Try:
    [        ] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    [        ] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    [        ] BUILD FAILED in 3m 11s
    [        ] Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
    [        ] Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
    [        ] See https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
    [ +400 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 192.0s)
    [   +4 ms] "flutter apk" took 210,111ms.
    [   +4 ms] Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
    [        ] 
               #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
               #1      buildGradleApp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:411:7)
               <asynchronous suspension>
               #2      _AndroidBuilderImpl.buildApk (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_builder.dart:101:7)
               <asynchronous suspension>
               #3      BuildApkCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_apk.dart:103:5)
               <asynchronous suspension>
               #4      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1157:12)
               <asynchronous suspension>
               #5      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1009:27)
               <asynchronous suspension>
               #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
               <asynchronous suspension>
               #7      AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
               <asynchronous suspension>
               #8      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:197:13)
               <asynchronous suspension>
               #9      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:278:9)
               <asynchronous suspension>
               #10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
               <asynchronous suspension>
               #11     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
               <asynchronous suspension>
               #12     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:234:5)
               <asynchronous suspension>
               #13     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:64:9)
               <asynchronous suspension>
               #14     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:12)
               <asynchronous suspension>
               #15     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
               <asynchronous suspension>
               #16     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
               <asynchronous suspension>
               #17     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:73:10)
               <asynchronous suspension>
               #18     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:90:3)
               <asynchronous suspension>
    [   +2 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 0ms
    [   +1 ms] Running shutdown hooks
    [        ] Shutdown hooks complete
    [        ] exiting with code 1
```

### **The Fix**

The fix was updating the buildscript repositories in the `build.gradle` file.
Earlier we used `jcenter()` but now we have to use `mavenCentral()` it seems.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
      //jcenter()      // Does not work any more! (Forbidden) 
        mavenCentral() // Repo that works. 
    }

    dependencies {
        // Don't confuse gradle with the Android gradle plugin (Grr)!
        // Android gradle https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1' //flutter 1.17.5
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'  // Flutter 2.0.6 NullSafety
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'  // Flutter 2.0.6 NullSafety
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'  // Firebase for Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)  Push Notifications on Android. 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, strangely, all I needed to do was restart my computer.

Answer (score -1):

Just found the issue and change to mavenCentral.